# Excluding the two types of users in django

Tags: python, django

I have an application in django and wants in my view exclude anonymous users and users who are admins (those who have a flag superuser).

I already have code that excludes anonymous users, but how else to put here users who are admins?

My model

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

Here is my query:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return User.objects.all().exclude(id=settings.ANONYMOUS_USER_ID)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add the exclude by `is_superuser` field:

```
User.objects.all().exclude(id=settings.ANONYMOUS_USER_ID) \
                  .exclude(is_superuser=True)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works in one case. Can you look at the update my post? I need exclude User form different model...

Comment: Use the `MyModel.objects.exclude(user__id=settings.ANONYMOUS_USER_ID) .exclude(user__is_superuser=True)` query.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also using `Q`

```
from django.db.models import Q
User.objects.exclude(Q(id=settings.ANONYMOUS_USER_ID) | Q(is_superuser=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

All admins have an attribut `is_staff=True`.

`User.objects.all().exclude(id=settings.ANONYMOUS_USER_ID).exclude(is_staff=True)`

Answer (score 0):

```
User.objects.all().exclude(id=)
```

... and you can specify who you ***don't*** want it to have access.